# Can I grow blackberries (brambles) from cut back stems?

Tags: propagation, blackberry

We have been removing a thicket of brambles from one area of our garden in the UK, but have another area we would quite like to be a thorny wilderness as a natural barrier.

I known brambles can take root where stems touch the ground so I wondered, if I just toss the freshly cut material onto bare soil, are they likely to take?

If not, how easy is it to take cuttings or otherwise get a few dozen tiny plants established?

Answer (score 3):

In my experience (of cutting down huge masses of brambles on my allotment) they don't grow from cut stems lying on the ground. They will root from vines rambling across the ground so if the live plants are nearby, you could try training/stretching a vine to the appropriate area and then pinning it to the ground. Alternatively you could dig up some of the roots and replant them. You will probably end up digging the roots out anyway because otherwise the brambles will keep on coming back.
Personally I wouldn't plant brambles in a garden as they're so invasive and a pain to get rid of. Something like Holly or pyracantha would be preferable IMO.